# Conditional Insert on date in MySql

Tags: mysql, insert

I have two tables (`employee` & `log_sheet`) and I want to insert the date of today into `log_sheet` when there is no record found in `log_sheet` for the user. If there is a record, it should return some value.

```
SELECT employee.id,
       employee.name,
       log_sheet.`date`
FROM   employee
       LEFT OUTER JOIN log_sheet
                    ON employee.id = log_sheet.employee_id
WHERE  employee.name = 'admin'
```

Comment: do you ask for script insert or script select?

Comment: Can it be possible to be something like "if there is no records found returns null value and inserts date of today, otherwise returns some value to tell the data exists".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to make sure that every employee has at least one log_sheet, right?

Something like this should work:

```
INSERT INTO log_sheet (employee_id, date)
    SELECT id, DATE(NOW()) 
    FROM   employee
    WHERE  name = 'admin' 
      AND  id NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT employee_id FROM log_sheet )
```

To preview what this would do, add `#` before the `INSERT` line.

Answer (score 0):

Try query bellow:

```
insert into log_sheet (date, employee_id) 
(
SELECT now(),
    employee.id
FROM employee
LEFT OUTER JOIN log_sheet ON employee.id = log_sheet.employee_id
WHERE employee.name = 'admin' AND log_sheet.`date` IS NULL
)
```